# How can a non-operator player run this command by clicking on a clickable tellraw text in 1.13+?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

My command is something simple:
`/tellraw @a {"text":"Test","clickEvent":{"action":"run_command","value":"/scoreboard players add Jimmy test 1"}}` The issue is that if a non-operator clicks on this text the command will not run. This question was asked for 1.12, but the /trigger command was removed, meaning those answers don't apply to the answer for this question. So, in 1.13+ Minecraft, how can I get around non-operators being unable to use the clickable text?

Comment: `/trigger` was not removed at all.

Comment: I closed this as a duplicate of an arbitrary `/trigger` question now, because there is no "the question only exists because wrong things were assumed" close reason.